Mac M1 Py2app build - Segmentation Fault 11
For the purposes of this question, I have a simple Python GUI (wx) application which I am building on an M1 Macbook Pro using Py2app. Latest setup tools (72.2.0) produces an error on M1/M2, so as per this (https://github.com/ronaldoussoren/py2app/issues/531), I have rolled back to Setuptools version 71.0.0.
At the end of the build, I can see there is a 'Segmentation Fault 11' reported. The resulting .app opens and runs on the build machine, but moving this to anotehr M2 mac, results in a crash with Segmentation Fault 11. Any suggestions would be great.
Example app:
import wx
import wx.stc as stc

class MainWindow(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, id, title):
        messageFile = "message.txt"
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, title, size=(410, 208), style=wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE & ~ (wx.RESIZE_BORDER | wx.MAXIMIZE_BOX))
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self, wx.ID_ANY)
        self.logWindow = wx.stc.StyledTextCtrl(self.panel, -1, pos=(10, 5), size=(390, 145), style=wx.TE_MULTILINE | wx.TE_PROCESS_ENTER)
        self.logWindow.SetMarginWidth(1, 0)
        self.logWindow.StyleClearAll()
        self.Centre()
        self.Show()

        with open(messageFile) as f:
            lines = f.readlines()[0]
            wx.CallAfter(self.logWindow.AppendText, lines)

app = wx.App()
MainWindow(None, -1, 'My App')
app.MainLoop()

Example setup.py:
"""
This is a setup.py script generated by py2applet

Usage:
    python setup.py py2app
"""

from setuptools import setup

APP = ['Test_App.py']
OPTIONS = {
    'iconfile':'Test_App.icns'
    }

setup(
    app=APP,
    name='Test_App',
    options={'py2app': OPTIONS},
    setup_requires=['py2app'],
)

